# How to create a facebook pop-up app on my web site where the user can enter their email address when a facebook button is pressed?

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I have a "Connect With Facebook" button on my web site and when it is clicked on I would like to have a facebook app pop-up that has some instructions and a space for then to enter their email address. Then a submit button for then to click on.
How do I do that? Or can I do that?
Clay

Comment: can u elaborate more on what your aim is? why do want the user to enter his email id and why should it be linked with facebook login. If you are referring to login via facebook, you can consult the [facebook developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `email` to the list of permissions your app requires and use one of the newer login buttons the new API now has available...the older Connect With Facebook appears to be old and going away. Here's a couple of choices for you to look into: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/